# Perl Inserting string into a url at specific places

Tags: regex, string, perl, url, insert

**I have the following piece of code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw(HELLO GOODBYE);  

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my $url = URI->new($_);
   my $query = $url->query;

foreach (@insert_words) {
  # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
  local our $insert_word = $_;

  local our @queries;
  if (defined $query) {
      $query =~ m{
          ^(.*[/=])([^/=&]*)((?:[/=&].*)?)\z
          (?{
              if (length $2) {
            push @queries, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
                  push @queries, "$1$insert_word$3";
                  push @queries, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
              }
          })
          (?!)
      }x;
  }

      if (@queries) {
          for (@queries) {
              $url->query($_);
              print $url, "\n";
          }
      }
      else {
          print $url, "\n";
      }
  }
}


__DATA__
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7
```

**The above piece of code works correctly and produces the following output:**

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7
```

As you can see it inserts the words in the array at specific places in the url.

**What I am now having problems with:**

I would now like to add the functionality to do all the possible combinations of `HELLO` and `GOODBYE` (or whatever is in the `@insert_words`) as well, for example it should also add the following url's to the output I already get:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=GOODBYE
```

But I do not know how to go about this in the best way?

Your help with this will be much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: The output you've shown here has only of the elements in `@insert_words`. On what all combinations will be applied then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Please* don't use fancy regexes like that - they are an experimental feature of Perl and are far from simple to comprehend.

If I understand you then you need to do this recursively.

I think you want all variations of the URL with each query parameter as it is, or preceded, succeeded, or replaced by every value in `@insert_words`.

This seems to do what you ask. It uses [`URI::QueryParam`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aQueryParam) to split up the query portion of the URL properly instead of using your nasty regex. It does produce substantially more combinations than you show in your question but I can see no other way of interpreting your requirement.

The number of possible variations is 49. Each parameter can have its original value, or be preceded, succeeded or replaced by either of two values. That is seven possible values for each parameter and so 7² or 49 different variations for two parameters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my @insert_words = qw/ HELLO GOODBYE /;

my @urls;

sub mod_param {
    my ($url, $paridx, @insertions) = @_;

    my @params = $url->query_param;
    return if $paridx > $#params;

    my $key = $params[$paridx];
    my $oldval = $url->query_param($key);

    my @variations = ($oldval);
    push @variations, ($oldval.$_, $_.$oldval, $_) for @insertions;

    for my $val (@variations) {
        $url->query_param($key, $val);
        if ($paridx == $#params) {
          push @urls, "$url";
        }
        else {
          mod_param($url, $paridx + 1, @insertions);
        }
    }
    $url->query_param($key, $oldval);
}

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $url = URI->new($_);
    @urls = ();
    mod_param($url, 0, @insert_words);
    print $_, "\n" for @urls;
}

__DATA__
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7
```

**output**

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9HELLO&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=HELLO&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9GOODBYE&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE9&other=GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=HELLO7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=HELLO
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=7GOODBYE
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=GOODBYE7
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=GOODBYE&other=GOODBYE
```

Comment: Excellent thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you . What changes would I need to make to your code to give the same output as my code with the regex did i.e without doing all the combinations of the `@insert_words`, just do the precede, succeed and replace for each of the `@insert_words`. The reason I ask is because I need one piece of code to do all the combinations (exactly how your answer shows me) and another to give the output without all the combinations (as my program with the regex already does), but I want to get rid of the regex in mine and use your method, thanks

Comment: @perl-user: I really don't understand what you want. You should open a new question, and explain exactly what you mean by "without all the combinations".

Comment: I will look. Please accept one of the answers to this question unless none of them have been any use to you.

Comment: Certainly, apologies - I thought I already had, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What would I need to change to get it to stop outputting the original url `http://www.example.com/index.php?route=9&other=7` again in the output (as seen in the first line of the output)? thanks for your help.

Comment: Other than just deleting the first element of the array `@urls` each time to get rid of it? thanks